# I am getting an error message in Oracle SQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying the following code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sal2
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT sal
    FROM emp
END
```

And I'm getting this error

> Error at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
>   null pragma raise return select update while with
>   << continue close current delete fetch lock
>   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
>   merge pipe purge
>   5.  from emp
>   6.  return 1
>   7. END

What I want to do is to get a `sal` column from `emp` table.

Comment: Add a semi-column at the end (;)

Comment: @zip
Still getting same error
 `create or replace procedure sal2
AS
BEGIN
 select sal
 from emp
END;`

Here is error
/n
`Error at line 6: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
    
    << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge

4.  select sal
5.  from emp
6. END;
`

Comment: You should read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with code as following;

```
create or replace procedure sal2
 AS
 Lv_var number; -- added variable for holding select value
 BEGIN

 select sal
 Into lv_var -- into is needed in select
 from emp; -- you missed this semicolon
  -- you must use where clause as into variable can hold single value
  -- so you must restrict this query to return only 1 record. 

 END; -- you missed this semicolon
 /
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to put the semicolon at the end of each line and after the END keyword. Then the SELECT statement is also wrong you have to load the result in a variable.

Here is the solution for multiple rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sal2
AS

    CURSOR c_salaries IS SELECT salary FROM employees;
    TYPE t_salaries IS TABLE OF c_salaries%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_salaries t_salaries;    

BEGIN
    OPEN c_salaries;
    FETCH c_salaries BULK COLLECT INTO v_salaries;
    CLOSE c_salaries;
END;
```

And one for a single row result.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sal2
AS

    v_salary employees.salary%rowtype;    

BEGIN
    SELECT salary INTO v_salary 
        FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 100;
END;
```